# Routing issue. Url becomes parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a url with path `/user_management/edit_official/:id`

its corresponding output from `rake routes` is

```
user_management_update_official POST   /user_management/edit_official/:id(.:format)           {:controller=>"user_management/employees", :action=>"update_official"}
```

When I try to access url via form, url is not reached, because the url `/user_management/edit_official/:id` becomes a parameter.

Following is the log file entry?

> Started POST "/user_management/edit_official/31" for 127.0.0.1 at
>   2012-01-02 11:05:21 +0530   Processing by ErrorsController#index as
>   HTML
>
> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"DED4E/9w/GDUQdjZ27mrUWrYBgipgHnNvS8mOjdaNXU=",
>   "employee"=>{"empl_id"=>"", "confirmation_date"=>"",
>   "designation_id"=>"", "rep_head1_id"=>"", "payment_mode"=>"",
>   "pf_number"=>"", "bank_name"=>"", "pt_applicable"=>"false",
>   "reg_date"=>"", "employee_type_id"=>"", "joining_date"=>"",
>   "rep_head2_id"=>"", "pf_applicable"=>"false",
>   "bank_account_number"=>"", "empl_email_id"=>"false",
>   "last_working_date"=>""}, "designation_level"=>"L-5b",
>   "user"=>{"username"=>"dsaf.adsfas", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "commit"=>"Next", "a"=>"user_management/edit_official/31"}

### Is there any reason for this. Thanks.

EDIT: Form included

```
<% url = user_management_update_official_path(@employee) %>
    <%= form_for(@employee, :url => url, :html => { :enctype => 'multipart/form-data'} ) do |f| %>
      <div id="employee_details" class="employee_form_steps">
        <%= render :partial => 'user_management/employees/official_information', 
          :locals => { :f => f} %>
        </div>
        <div class="btn_row">
          <%= content_tag(:button, '< Back', :id => 'official_information_back', :class => 'grey') %>
          <%= f.submit 'Next', :class => 'green', :style => 'margin:0px;padding:4px;width:50px;' %>
          <%= content_tag(:button, 'Cancel', :class => 'cancel grey') %>
        </div>

      <% end %>
```

Comment: What's the actual error you get in the rails log?

Comment: @AndrewF, there is no other error other than that I have copied in question,

Answer (score 0):

The error must lie in your `routes.rb`

The rule in this file is: first match, first served.

Try to take the line corresponding to `"errors#index"` and put it under the one describing `/user_management/edit_official/:id`

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was the `http` method used for form. The `form_for` used `put` method while, in routes I specified `POST`. Changing `POST` to `PUT`, made everything work.